# Can one add a Nvidia GPU to a Dell Precision T3500 to use?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, workstation, dell-precision

Can one install a Nvidia GPU such as Tesla™ C2075 to a Dell Precision T3500 to use?

Thanks for any helpful answers!

Answer (score 0):

Dell [says](https://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/precision-t3500/pd), in their specifications for the Precision T3500:

> Support for 2 PCI Express x16 Gen 2 graphics cards up to 150 watts (total):

and the [Tesla C2075 datasheet](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/43395/NV-DS-Tesla-C2075.pdf) says:

> SYSTEM INTERFACE: PCIe x16 Gen2
>   POWER CONSUMPTION: 225W TDP

So while it can be installed, it probably will be too much for the power supply, as it goes over Dell's recomendations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible to use a GPU on a T3500?

Comment: @md98 I think so, as long as it is PCI Express X16 and doesn't consume more than 150 W.

Comment: Is it better to use a NVIDIA Quadro 4000 for parallel computing or super computing?

Comment: @md98 I don't know.

Comment: @md98 I think Quadro GPUs are for 3d animation and Tesla GPUs are for supercomputing

Comment: You could always swap the PSU - for most part they are standard.

Comment: Probably they only say this TDP limit as cooling may not be enough. Keep an eye on the temps and you'll probably be right.

Comment: Any PCI-e graphics card which does not exceed power drawn of cooling requirements should fit. These things are more of less standarised. PCI-e x16 is usualy recommended for lower latency, which is useful for CUDA and openCL, but x8 and x1 can also work fine for more grahics outputs (e.g. when you want to connect more screens).